# Dynamically create a class / object using headings from an excel worksheet C# win forms

Tags: c#, excel, object

I would like to loop through an excel work sheet and create an object from the data in each row. I am hoping to do this using C# and winforms. I can link the file to my win form however I am not sure how I add the data into the correct object properties.

Any pointers at all would be appreciated.

Comment: Pointers: [ask] and [tour]. What do you expect for an answer to this question? We cannot see what you tried or used ... even the slightest hint would be useful. Like are you using a DataGrid component or maybe a [DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)?

Comment: Do you have Office interop working for reading row data? Is the row data in a consistent format? Do you need an anonymous/dynamic object for each row? As Fildor said, please provide helpful details if you wish for helpful answers.

Comment: I don't think you can create a class dynamically based on an Excel header. You class and its properties need to exist and correspond to the Excel worksheet and its content. Also, which version of `c#` are you using ? which library is letting you read from an Excel file ?